# ng2-dragula move item without removing it on drag start

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, dragula, ng2-dragula

I am using ng2-dragula in my Angular application and what I want is to be able to drag an element from the list but without the default behaviour of dragula which is removing it on drag start.

I want the element to stay where it is until I drop it (because it is moving all the elements in the list if it is removed and it's baffling). I would like something like the copy function, where the element is not removed on drag start.

I mention that using copy method and removing it manual from code is not an option because I have the copy function configured for another list and will mess things up there too.

One solution that I found is to create a new element, append it to the place drag started and in the end delete it on the drop event but it is just an ugly workaround.

Did someone faced this problem aswell and found a solution?